# Nextflow: No signature of Method: chr() is applicable for argument types; unknown variable

Tags: plink, nextflow

I was trying to use plink in nextflow. My first process will split the input (single bed|bim|fam file) into 22 chromosomes (each with bed|bim|fam files) which would be used in subsequent processes. My code and error log is below. Any help?

```
params.dir='data/'
params.publish="output2/"
Channel
.fromFilePairs("${params.dir}*.{bed,bim,fam}",size:3)
.set {data}

Channel
.of(1..22)
.set {chr_names}
    
process step1a {
publishDir params.publish
input:
tuple val(sample_name), path(bfiles) from data
output:
tuple val("${prefix}"), path("${prefix}.step1a.{bed,bim,fam}") into step1a_results
tuple val("${prefix}"), path("${prefix}.step1b.{bed,bim,fam}") into step1a_out
tuple val("${prefix}"), path("${prefix}.step1b.bim") into step1a_bims
path("${prefix}.log") into step1a_logs
path("${prefix}.step1a.dupvar") into step1a_duplicates
path("${prefix}.step1a.log") into step1a_log
path("${prefix}.step1b.log") into step1_log
script:
prefix=chr"${chr_names}"
"""
plink --bfile "${sample_name}" --chr "${chr_names}" --out "${prefix}" --make-bed
plink --bfile "${prefix}" --list-duplicate-vars ids-only suppress-first --out "${prefix}.step1a"
plink --bfile "${prefix}" --exclude "${prefix}.step1a.dupvar" --make-bed --out "${prefix}.step1a"
plink --bfile "${prefix}.step1a" --snps-only just-acgt --make-bed --out "${prefix}.step1b"
"""
}
process step1b {
publishDir params.publish
input:
tuple val(sample_name), path(bfiles) from step1a_out
tuple val(bims), path("${prefix}.step1b.bim") from step1a_bims
output:
tuple val("${sample_name}"), path("${sample_name}.step1c.{bed,bim,fam}") into step1b_results
path("${sample_name}.step1c.log") into step1b_logs
path("${sample_name}.step1b.snplist.txt") into step1b_snplist
script:
"""
awk '{ if ((\\\$5=="T" && \\\$6=="A")||(\\\$5=="A" && \\\$6=="T")||(\\\$5=="C" && \\\$6=="G")||(\\\$5=="G" && \\\$6=="C")) print \\\$2, "ambig" ; else print \\\$2 ;}' "${prefix}.step1b.bim" | grep ambig > "${prefix}.step1b.snplist.txt"
plink --bfile "${prefix}.step1b --exclude "${prefix}.step1b.snplist.txt" --make-bed --out "${prefix}.step1c"
"""
}
```

The error message is:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 20.10.0
Launching `t4.hf` [zen_picasso] - revision: b0ff8db413
[-        ] process > step1a -
[-        ] process > step1b -
Error executing process > 'step1a (1)'

Caused by:
[-        ] process > step1a -
[-        ] process > step1b -
Error executing process > 'step1a (1)'

Caused by:
  No signature of method: chr() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [DataflowQueue(queue=[DataflowVariable(value=1), DataflowVariable(value=2), DataflowVariable(value=3), DataflowVariable(value=4), DataflowVariable(value=5), DataflowVariable(value=6), DataflowVariable(value=7), DataflowVariable(value=8), DataflowVariable(value=9), DataflowVariable(value=10), DataflowVariable(value=11), DataflowVariable(value=12), DataflowVariable(value=13), DataflowVariable(value=14), DataflowVariable(value=15), DataflowVariable(value=16), DataflowVariable(value=17), DataflowVariable(value=18), DataflowVariable(value=19), DataflowVariable(value=20), DataflowVariable(value=21), DataflowVariable(value=22), DataflowVariable(value=groovyx.gpars.dataflow.operator.PoisonPill@28c22659)])]
Possible solutions: run(), run(), any(), is(java.lang.Object), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), tap(groovy.lang.Closure)

Source block:
  prefix=chr"${chr_names}"
  """
  plink --bfile "${sample_name}" --chr "${chr_names}" --out "${prefix}" --make-bed
  plink --bfile "${prefix}" --list-duplicate-vars ids-only suppress-first --out "${prefix}.step1a"
  plink --bfile "${prefix}" --exclude "${prefix}.step1a.dupvar" --make-bed --out "${prefix}.step1a"
  plink --bfile "${prefix}.step1a" --snps-only just-acgt --make-bed --out "${prefix}.step1b"
  """

Tip: when you have fixed the problem you can continue the execution adding the option `-resume` to the run command line
```

If I use "prefix=chr"${chr_names}" " inside the code block (""") it shows: unknown variable 'prefix'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documation re [conditional scripts](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#conditional-scripts) is useful here:

> Process scripts can contain conditional statements by simply prefixing
> the script block with the keyword `script:`. By doing that the
> interpreter will evaluate all the following statements as a code block
> that must return the script string to be executed.

But the statements don't necessarily need to be conditional. I.e. they can just be declarations like in your example. You get the error 'No signature of Method: chr()' because Nextflow interprets 'chr' as a method call when you use:

```
prefix = chr"${chr_name}"
```

If your intention is to simply add the 'chr' prefix to each chromosome name, you'd need:

```
prefix = "chr${chr_name}"
```

Notice that I changed your variable name. This is because in your code, you still need to feed in the channel of chromosome names. The easiest way to do this is to use the [each qualifier](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html?highlight=script#input-repeaters):

```
process myprocess {

    input:
    tuple val(sample_name), path(bfiles) from plink_data
    each chr_name from chr_names

    script:
    prefix = "chr${chr_name}"

    """
    echo "My sample name is: ${sample_name}"
    echo "My prefixed chromosome name is: ${prefix}"
    """
}
```

Unless you need chromosome names without the 'chr' prefix, another solution might be to simply add the prefix to each one initially and simply avoid having to prefix them later:

```
Channel
    .of(1..22)
    .map { "chr${it}" }
    .set { chr_names }
```

Comment: It seems process 1 and 2 running in random order. Is there any way to specify that after finishing the first process, the second process will start. Because the outputs of the first process will be the input of the second process. In my case my second process shows error because it does not find an input, which is an output of the first process. Did I clarify the matter?

Comment: I suspect the problem arises because you've specified two input and output channels ('step1a_out' and 'step1a_bims'). It's not clear to me why you need the two channels, since the 'step1a_bims' looks like a subset of 'step1a_out'? Please see [understanding how multiple input channels work](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-understand-how-multiple-input-channels-work)

Comment: Ohh! Thank you. Just one thing, How could I declare prefix of the previous process output as an input of the current process. I have chr(1-22).step1b.bed|bim|fam as output of process step1a; Now I want to declare only chr(1-22) as input in the step1b process. I want different suffix inside process step1b. I am not sure if I could clarify the issue.

Comment: Does my answer to your most recent [question](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/15590/nextflow-ordering-the-execution-of-processes-outputs-of-process-a-are-inputs-o/15594) answer your question?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Still wondering how could I declare prefix (characters before first .) as input in the next process which is the output of the previous process.

Comment: No worries at all @zillurrahman. If I understand correctly, the easy way would be to include it in your output tuple as an extra value for your prefix. But if it's already part of (i.e. the prefix) of another value then you could again use the [map operator](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#map) to get it back. Perhaps something like: `map { some_name, some_thing -> tuple( some_name.substring(0, some_name.indexOf('.')), some_name, some_thing ) }` ? A concrete example would be great if the above doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Steve. I tried different ways but failed, maybe because I am new in nextflow. My files are chr1-22.step1b.bed|bim|fam in out_ch1. I need a way to find chr1 to chr22 as prefix for the next input so I can modify the suffixes. for example input chr1-22.step1b.bed|bim|fam --some command --out chr1-22.step1c.bed|bim|fam into out_ch3.
Also how can I use subset of the outputs channel. From above example I need only chr1-22.step1b.bim as a $bim --some command to run -out chr1-22.step1b.snp.txt. So far I tried "filter" but failed. Thanks again for helping all the way.

Comment: `@Steve`, I tried to filter as: `tuple val(bim), path(bims) from step1a_bim.filter{bim -> bims=~ /*bim/}` But I am getting error `unexpected input:` Also I am still not getting the prefix correctly. Perhaps any example would be helpful. Do you know any training module to run plink, gwas in nextflow?

Comment: Sorry @zillurrahman - I'm not sure I can get you a useful answer without a minimal example of exactly what you're trying to do. On file-like objects you can call `getSimpleName()` to get the prefix, see [check file attributes](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/script.html#check-file-attributes). The problem is that this won't work on a tuple of files. I guess I'm confused as to why you can't just include the chromosome name in the output tuple of the first process? This way you'd avoid having to try and find the prefix in the first place.

Comment: Using my answer above as an example, your output declaration could look like: `tuple val(sample_name), val(chr_name), path("${sample_name}.${chr_name}.step1b.{bed,bim,fam}") into step1a_out`. Also, I'm not aware of any good plink/gwas pipelines but you could try having a look here: https://github.com/nextflow-io/awesome-nextflow. HTH.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In that case how can I declare inputs in the next process? If I use step1a_out two time (first for bfiles, and then for bim) I got error `Channel 'step1a_out' has been used twice as an input by process 'step1b'`

Comment: If I understand correctly, the input declaration for the next process will be basically the same as the first processes' output declaration. If that's the case, you'd need: `tuple val(sample_name), val(chr_name), path(bfiles)`. Since the bfiles tuple will contain the bim  file as the second element, you should be able to access it directly with `${bfiles[1]}`. Alternatively, in your script block, you could unpack the bfiles: `(bed, bim, fam) = bfiles`, then just use `${bim}` as your variable. If these variables don't need to be global, consider instead: `def (bed, bim, fam) = bfiles`. HTH.

Comment: Thanks a lot `@Steve` . It works. Just one thing. How could I specify output directory of my results? I tried `params.publish='output2'` then in each process `publishDir params.publish`. I got only link of the output files in `output2`. How could I get actual result files in my desired directory? Again thanks a lot for helping me all the way.

Comment: Ohh! I got it. I just need to mention `mode: 'copy'` in `publishDir` declaration. Thanks!